# Play 2 framework spring data with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, playframework-2.0, spring-data

I am new to Play Framework and I am trying to do a simple example to understand how it works. I have used the template play-spring-data-jpa to start. I would like to use MySQL in a persistent way and that is why I chose it.

I started with h2 to understand how it works and then tried to move to connecting to a MySQL local database.

I followed the steps to use JPA from https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaJPA to get a persistence unit.

The code works fine with h2, but when I switch to MySQL, I get an error.

The connection with the database works fine, as I get the message:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/brainUp?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
```

But right after that message I get the following one:

```
[error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - could not get database metadata
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
[error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'sequences' in information_schema
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
```

I don't quite understand the message and I have been searching for quite long and have not found anything that makes me understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show persistence.xml or application.conf where you defined dialect.

Comment: Thank you for the interest. I revised the persistence.xml again and found the error there. As I think you suspected it was about the dialect.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you  @Krzysiek for the interest. I revised the persistence.xml again and found the error there. As I think you suspected it was about the defined dialect.

As I previously used h2, so the dialect was defined for that instead of for MySQL.

Here's the new persistence.xml which works fine, in case someone encounters the same problem as me.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I also would like to note for new users like me that if you want to create the tables from java code you should set   to create-drop, and just to use and edit data stored you might want to switch it to "update" instead, when the database is created and will not suffer structural changes anymore.